# Sharing variables acoss several python files

Tags: python

I have tasked to modify a wx python gui based program which has several .py files.
I would like to share some variables defined in a.py and use them in b.py 
The 10 -15 variables are of this form:

```
 Amode = [SINGLE]
 Format = [A] etc...
```

I would like to use them in b.py.
How do I go about it? I read about Pickle but still not clear how to use it well.

Answer (score 3):

```
import a

// do something with a.Amode

// do something with a.Format
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the best idea, in this case, is to either place the variables on the module directly or use some shared dataStore. I like the [Borg pattern](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/) for this.

Basically do this:

```
#in borg.py
class Borg:
    __shared_state = {}
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
```

Everywhere else:

```
import borg
drone = borg.Borg()
drone.foo = 1;
```

Obviously, you can limit this by defining `__set__`.

As to placing variables on modules directly, well, I'm not really a fan of having stateful variables publicly accessible on modules, but that is probably mostly me.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are singletons (no matter how many times it's imported, it's only actually imported once, and that once is shared), so what I often do for this use case is to create a modules named, say, "shared.py", and put the data I want shared across other modules in it.  Then, in those other modules:

```
import shared
# Use a shared variable/object
print shared.Amode
# Changes to the shared data are seen in all modules where it's imported.
shared.Amode = aNewValue
```

This has the nice effect of keeping all my shared data in its own namespace, "shared".